# JavaScript V8 security

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, v8

I was reading about **V8 JavaScript engine** and was shocked that Node JS and Browser JS use the same V8 engine and that's way produce the same Machine Code.

Question:
Is it browser responsibility to **protect** from accessing **Network/OS/etc**? It seems like huge field for different kind of injections and lot of security risks...

Comment: Browser security only involves browser-supplied APIs. V8 doesn't know anything about `document`, `window`, `localStorage`, etc etc.

Comment: Occam's razor: *if* V8 was so insecure/sharing so problematic, because it is so widely used, in a field so incredibly popular and constantly attacked by so many attackers, shouldn't it already be a known security nightmare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Security is obviously a big concern on the web platform, so there are several layers of protection built in:

- V8 itself doesn't even provide access to OS or network. It's a virtual machine, and one of the consequences of running stuff (like JavaScript code) in a virtual machine is that it provides insulation from the host system. (The OS/network functionality you see in node.js is provided by node.js and doesn't exist in Chrome.)
- Chrome additionally sandboxes the renderer processes that V8 runs in. So even if someone found a way to exploit V8 to generate and run arbitrary machine code (which V8 tries very hard to make impossible), they'd still have to find a way to break out of the sandbox (which prevents wild access to the system; for example renderer processes can't even read files from disk or write files to disk).

The fact that "the same V8 engine" runs on the server and in the browser does not constitute a risk. All HTTP based interaction between server and client is the same regardless of what software runs on both (whether it's, e.g., Apache/Firefox or node.js/Chrome or any other combination).

Injecting things into V8 should be really really hard (it's a bug when it's possible!), so if you have specific ideas how to do that, we'd like to work with you to fix it ;-)

It all boils down to: there's a clearly defined set of things that JavaScript programs can do in the browser (which should all be safe), and the platform makes it impossible to do anything else. If it *is* possible to do something else, it's a security bug, and you'll (probably) earn a bug bounty when you report it.